# Dual Monitor Resolution Problem with KVM Switch

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, kvm-virtualization, display-resolution, ubuntu-studio

Trying to setup a dual monitor environment with one monitor running through a KVM Switch.

The first monitor gets detected just fine at 1280x960 (no KVM switch) but the other one (running through the switch) isn't allowing anything above a max resolution of 1024x768.

[image]

There are some posts out there dealing with older hardware and old Ubuntu versions. Any suggestions for a fix?

Details: Running a setup of Dual Monitors 2x Samsung 19" SyncMaster 940BF, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Ubuntu Studio, KVM is a d-link dkvm-2k

Comment: How old is this KVM switch? Sometimes they just can't support high resolutions.

Comment: @Zacharee1 it's a D-Link DKVM-2K with model number DKVM-2KU and HW Version 1.02. But I couldn't put a date of purchase on it. Got it used ...

Comment: Looks pretty old. You say the monitor works fine without the switcher, and since switchers don't have any video driver interfaces, it must be a limitation in the switcher itself.

Comment: @Zacharee1 it seems specifications on the D-Link page don't apply to early models. It states a video resolution up to 2048 x 1536
http://www.dlink.com/de/de/home-solutions/connect/kvm-switches/dkvm-2ku-2-port-kvm-switch-with-usb-port-and-built-in-cables

Comment: Maybe you have a defective switcher or VGA cable then.

Comment: It only has VGA cables ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all future readers who run into this problem: There is a brute-force solution even with that KVM switch (been there, done that).

Write a short shell script which uses xrandr to set up the monitors.
In that script, define a new mode line, add it to the affected output, and order it to be used.
In my case, it looks like this:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080" 148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1920x1080
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --rotate left --auto --output DVI-0 --right-of DisplayPort-0 --auto --primary --mode 1920x1080
```

Then, put this script with "x" permission into your `~/.config/autostart-scripts/` directory.

Hope this helps!
Jörg

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the hardware to test this anymore. Is anyone with this problem able to confirm? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution was to trash the D-Link KVM Switch. The following KVM Switch worked out of the box with no problems, just beautiful:

**Aten 2-Port USB KVM Switch**
Model: **CS62US**
Features:
* Control 2 Computers with one Monitor
* USB Mouse and Keyboard
* Switch with Hotkeys
Hardware: 2x Samsung 19" SyncMaster 940BF
Software: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Ubuntu Studio

PS I'm posting this because I ran through 6 KVM switches that didn't work. Hope this helps other Ubuntu users save time.

Comment: I will try your suggesting of getting the Aten 2-port, as I can't get the one I have working with two monitors. Let see.

Answer (score 0):

find KVM switch support "FULL-time EDID emulation" will solve the issue. 
It was the OLD KVM switch you have(some new KVM switches are still not support this function) did not support EDID data communication between shared monitors and connected systems.